# Windows won't boot - blinking underscore

Tags: windows

when I turn my computer on, I get the screen with the'press f2 to run setup' etc.

After that, I get a screen with only a flashing hyphon on it.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What windows are you using? What where you doing before this happen?

Comment: I was trying to restore my boot partition. I rebooted, then this.

Comment: My current and previous PCs both did this at boot if I had a USB drive (flash or HDD) plugged in during boot. Removing the drive and rebooting fixed the issue.

Comment: It's called a _cursor_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say.  Perhaps the hard disk has gone bad or the OS has a serious issue.  You could try booting from a live CD like knoppix to test memory and see whether the hard disk will mount.

Comment: I think I accident erased the boot partition

Comment: Most likely the data is unrecoverable then.  There are some tools that allow reconstruction of the boot partition but I can't help there.  perhaps gparted will do.  take a look at this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/recovering.html

Comment: [MiniTool Partition Recovery](http://www.minitool-partitionrecovery.com/) should be able to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the boot order in bios. My wifes PC was configured that way, that it tried to boot from every disc, cd, usb-stick or memory-card. If there was a memory-card in the card reader, then it showed the same behavior that you describe.